# App crash using setValue:forKey

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a mutable array "myArray" like:

```
{
    IdPregunta = 1;
    Respuestas =     (
                {
            IdResp = 1;
            Valor = 1;
        },
                {
            IdResp = 2;
            Valor = 0;
        }
    );
},
```

as a source of a table view.

As I need to change a boolean value when user tap a button into the cell, 
I am using the `setValue:forKey` method without luck:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
dict = [[[ myArray valueForKey:@"Respuestas"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:1];
        [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"Valor"];
```

App crashes without any "readable" message (Thread 1: breackpoint 1,3 3,3 5,3 ....).

I tried changing with

```
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"Valor"];
```

with same result.

Comment: Arrays don't contain key-value pairs...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no guarantee, that `dict` is really an `NSMutableDictionary` at run-time. Your initial reference assigned in

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

is immediately overwritten in the line below:

```
dict = [[[myArray valueForKey: @"Respuestas"] objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex: 1];
```

The value of `dict` is something else now. If you are lucky, `dict` is an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` after this line, but I would not bet on it... This renders the effect of

```
[dict setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey: @"Valor"];
```

unpredictable. Check the value of `dict` after the second assignment via `NSLog`:

```
NSLog(@"Value of dict is now %@", dict);
```

Another point is, that the result of

```
[[[myArray valueForKey: @"Respuestas"] objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex: 1]
```

seems to be undefined, if I read you example data structure correctly:

```
[myArray valueForKey: @"Respuestas"]
```

yields an array

```
(
    {
        IdResp = 1;
        Valor = 1;
    },
    {
        IdResp = 2;
        Valor = 0;
    }
);
```

the surrounding

```
[... objectAtIndex: 0]
```

yields a dictionary

```
{
    IdResp = 1;
    Valor = 1;
}
```

and the outermost call

```
[... objectAtIndex: 1]
```

seems undefined to me (since we got a dictionary, not an array). Your last example line

```
[valor setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"Valor"];
```

I cannot interpret. What's `valor`?